# Loading SQL Server SSIS assembly in Powershell background jobs

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, start-job

I am trying to run a SQL Server SSIS packages as a background job in Powershell 2.0 but the necessary assemblies don't appear to load.

I can load the DTS assembly without issue and run packages successfully in Powershell.

```
>[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS")
GAC    Version        Location                                                                                                                      
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                      
True   v2.0.50727     C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\9.0.242.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll
```

But when I try this in a background job it never complete and the job just continues in a running state.

```
$job=Start-Job -ScriptBlock {[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS")} 
Wait-Job $job
Receive-Job $job
```

What differences are there between a normal Powershell runspace and the space where the background job runs?

```
>$PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
CLRVersion                     2.0.50727.3625
BuildVersion                   6.0.6002.18111
PSVersion                      2.0
WSManStackVersion              2.0
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0}
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.1
```

Comment: I don't have this problem but I'm running PS on Windows 7 (Build Version = 6.1.7600.16385).

Comment: I ran your test code fine on my machine also. I"m on Windows 7 PS V2. I know XP can be a little flaky with jobs.

Comment: I was trying to run this on Win 2003 SP2 with SQL 2005 SSIS installed. I just tested on Win 2008 R2 and it seems to load ok. Guess its time to upgrade, thank you all.